# If $n-1$ is prime show it is relatively prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

If $n$ is a natural number, and $n-1$ is prime, show that,

$$\gcd(n-1, (n-2)!) = 1$$

I tried:

$$= \frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)...1}{(n-1)}$$

But what to do?

Comment: All the prime factors of $(n-2)!$ are less than or equal to $n-2$ and so coprime to the prime number $n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $$\gcd (n-1, (n-2)!) >1$$ Then there exists a number $m>1$ such that $m|n-1$ and $m| (n-2)!$. Because $n-1$ is prime, $m=n-1$. Thus $n-1 | (n-2)!$ Now because $n-1$ is prime and divides the product $(n-2)!$, it divides one of its factors, a contradiction (because all factors are smaller than $n-1$).

Answer (score 0):

If $n-1=p$(prime)

Wilson says: $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p\implies(p-1)!=kp-1$ for some integer $p$

$(n-1,(n-2)!)=(p,(p-1)!)=(p,kp-1)$